# method naming convention for sortBy orderBy with multiple arguments, best practices

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions, conventions, convention

For example i have table (e.g. in-memory collection) with `name` `lastname` fields and more.
Example JSON:

```
[
  {name: 'arina', lastname: 'anyone'},
  {name: 'bob',   lastname: 'zorro'},
  {name: 'bob',   lastname: 'black'},
]
```

now i want a data sorting method, that sorts the data by name and lastname

that means i want the result:

```
arina - anyone
bob   - black
bob   - zorro
```

but if i write something like

```
function sortByNameAndLastname(data) {
  //here i should first sort by lastname, then by name to get result i want
  sortByLastName(data);
  sortByName(data);
}
```

that is somehow confusing, if you read the order of calls.

What is the naming convention / best practices to name such method?

`sortByNameAndLastname` or `sortByLastnameAndName` ?

if you see SQL, there is a first case `ORDER BY name, lastname` returns the result i want.

Comment: @BenSmith yes its nice, and better then field1ANDfield2, but still confusing because of implementation.. if you sort first field1 then field2, you get the opposite sorting. So if i read sortByFirstThenSecond, i can assume both, is it about sorting priority, or about implementation sequence. Except its a standard convention, that i must assume its a priority.

Comment: Yes, it will be by implementation sequence as it will follow the SQL syntax. Naming methods is hard!

Comment: @BenSmith but implementation call sequence is opposite to sql syntax. sql says: order by first, second.  Implementation: second(); first();. And the method name... no idea, there must be some convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be consistent with SQL syntax and use the naming convention of:

`OrderBy<firstField>Then<SecondField>`

For example in your case:

`OrderByNameThenLastName`

Your "name" field really should be renamed "firstname", especially as you have a field called "lastname" for the surname.